table columns are not aligned when scrollable is active
I use AntDesign table, but columns are not aligned when I make my table scrollable
<Table
  columns={columns}
  dataSource={newInvestCategoryData}
  pagination={false}
  scroll={{
       y: '300px',
       x: 'max-content',
  }}
  rowKey={'codeId'}
/>

Here's the result:

I expect it's align left like this:

